# python find elements using selenium.webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to find the following element:

```
<input type="text" value="" action-data="text=邮箱/会员帐号/手机号" action-type="text_copy" class="W_input " name="username" ...
```

And here is the html tags section, there are multiple `input` with the same name and class properties. So I want to find it using the `normal_form` div property.

This code does not work:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[action-type="text_copy"]')
```

I think the field `action-type` is not a standard field.

What can I do?.
Thanks.

```
<div class="W_login_form" node-type="normal_form">
<div class="info_list" node-type="username_box">
    <div class="inp username ">
        <input type="text" value="" action-data="text=邮箱/会员帐号/手机号" action-type="text_copy" class="W_input " name="username" node-type="username" tabindex="1" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I am trying, and this way I can find the element.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='W_login_form']/div/div/input")
```

It finds the `div` with class `W_login_form` first, and looks for `div` and `div` step in, and last gets the `input`.

Do you have any good idea about it?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Can you please demostrate any Python code which you are using to try to solve the problem?

Comment: I am trying.
And this way I can find the emelent.

    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='W_login_form']/div/div/input")

It finds div with class 'W_login_form' first ,and look for div and div step in,and last get input .

Do u have any good idea about it.
: )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='info_list']//input")
```

Comment: What do the double / mean here?

Comment: double // means skipping levels, one means a direct child. you have only one div between the div with the class and the input.

Comment: another mistake is that you are looking in the div with the 'W_login_form' class, but the input is in the div with the 'info_list' class.

Comment: One more question，the custom filed node-type ,does it work fine this way :browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[action-type="text_copy"]')